# Python write to file uses unnecessary storage?

Tags: python, python-3.x

On my laptop, I got tabualr data in a list of strings, ~50k items in the list.
Each item in the list is a string that contains tab seperated values (.tsv).
I use the following python code to write these values to a tsv file:

```
 with open("path/to/file.tsv", 'w') as file:
    file.writelines(my_list_of_strings)
```

The size of the file created is over 10,000 KB.
Now when I open the file in Excel and make a minor manual change, like deleting a single row or even adding a new row, save the file, I notice the file size is much smaller.
Now the size of the tsv file is about 7,000 KB.

Why is that?

I also tried to iterate over the list and use `write()` for each item instead of `writelines()`. Plus, I tried comma seperated values and saved the file as csv instead tsv. Still same thing happens.

Each item in `my_list_of_strings` looks something like this:

`'-1.0000000e+00\t1.0002500e+03\t-1.0000000e+00\t0.0000000e+00\t5.3894500e+01\t2.7119400e+01\t-8.8790900e+00\t-4.5719900e+01\t1.0045900e+01\t1.1052600e+00\t-3.3619700e-01\t9.9792500e+00\t4.5077500e+01\t1.8811800e-01\t1.4068537e+12\t7.3581100e+05\n'`

Comment: Have you used any kind of diff/delta tool to look at what actually changed? The problem is presumably somewhere in the contents of `my_list_of_strings` (if it's not an issue in how your file is configured to be encoded -- if it's UTF-16 and Excel is re-saving as UTF-8, there's your difference), and you haven't shown us anything whatsoever about how it's generated / what it contains.

Comment: You should inspect the before/after file in a good text editor, diff tool or the command line `less`  tool on *ix. Excel might apply a different encoding, replace spaces with tabs or similar.

Comment: Is it possible that you are writing unicode through python, but somehow excel saves the file as ascii or something else?

Comment: @DaeMoohn, ...*which* unicode encoding is the question -- your most common (ASCII printable) characters will be written as one-byte in UTF-8, vs two bytes in UTF-16, four bytes in UTF-32...

Comment: If `less` or `diff` isn't informative, comparing `xxd`, `hexdump -C` or another hex dump of the two files presumably will be. Regardless, without a definitive description of the files' contents (or a [mcve] letting a file fitting this description be generated by folks reviewing the question), this isn't answerable.

Comment: I would guess that Excel completely rewrote your file and changed all the numbers.

Comment: Seconding the reformatting of numbers by Excel. The first number in your sample line is `-1.0000000e+00` which can be written as `-1` if you don't mind the loss of precision.

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely due to the encoding excel is using to save the data. Try creating the file through your python script, opening it in excel and saving it again without changing any of the data inside. See if the file size changes.